# Detect internal change to @Input property angular 4

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

I understand that ngOnChanges is fired when a components @Input property from its parent component. But how I can detect if an @Input property is changed within its component. I've not been able to find a good answer to that.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, You can use the **[`ngOnChanges()`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)** lifecycle method as also mentioned in older answers:

```
@Input() yourInput: string;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.doSomething(changes.yourInput.currentValue);
    // You can also use yourInput.previousValue and 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `@Input()` on setter methods so that you can take additional actions whenever new values is being set for an attribute.

Here is a sample component that demonstrates this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 (click)="name = 'Bye'">{{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {

  private _name: string;

  get name() {
    console.log("Returning name", this._name);
    return this._name;
  }

  @Input() 
  set name(newName) {
    console.log("Setting new name", newName);
    this._name = newName;
  }
}
```

This component when used in another component, can be specified somewhat like below:

```
  <hello  [name]="'Hi'"></hello>
```

In aboe example, initial value of `Hi` was set from external/parent component, and on click of text, value is updated to `Bye` internal to component.   In both cases, you will observe the `console.log` statement in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Output() or event emitter which needs to be caught by the parent component.